# PHP crypt function results : how does it work?

Tags: php, crypt

When I execute the next script in PHP :

```
 $hash1 = crypt('test','$2a$08$useasillystringforsalt$');<br/>
   echo 'hash1:'.$hash1.'<br/>';
   $hash2 = crypt('test','$2a$08$useasillystringforsaley3TiRUWCAPaejcvjzQFYCRitqtaPur6');<br/>
   echo 'hash2: '.$hash2.'<br/>';      
   $hash3 = crypt('test','$2a$08$useasillystringforsaley3TiRUWCAPaejcvjzQFYCRitqtaPur6');
<br/>
   echo 'hash3: '.$hash3.'<br/>';   
   $hash4 = crypt('test','$2a$08$useasillystringforsalfaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa');
<br/>
   echo 'hash4: '.$hash4.'<br/>';   
   $hash5 = crypt('test','$2a$08$useasillystringforsaldaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa');
<br/>
   echo 'hash5: '.$hash5.'<br/>';   
   $hash6 = crypt('test','$2a$08$useasillystringforsaleaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa');
<br/>
   echo 'hash6: '.$hash6.'<br/>';
```

I get the following results :

```
hash1: $2a$08$useasillystringforsaley3TiRUWCAPaejcvjzQFYCRitqtaPur6
<br/>
hash2: $2a$08$useasillystringforsaley3TiRUWCAPaejcvjzQFYCRitqtaPur6
<br/>
hash3: $2a$08$useasillystringforsaley3TiRUWCAPaejcvjzQFYCRitqtaPur6
<br/>
hash4: $2a$08$useasillystringforsaley3TiRUWCAPaejcvjzQFYCRitqtaPur6
<br/>
hash5: $2a$08$useasillystringforsalOnUtWGdo1WqxrpPXy7Lrt0SHVxn5XeU6
<br/>
hash6: $2a$08$useasillystringforsaley3TiRUWCAPaejcvjzQFYCRitqtaPur6
```

hash1 is the result of :

```
crypt('test',$2a$08$useasillystringforsalt);
```

My question is :

How can all the results be the same except for hash5 ?  I thought the 
slightest change in the salt would generate a completely different result.

Comment: According to the crypt documentation, crypt only cares about the first 22 digits of the salt.  That said, I'm not sure why it's not coming up different

Answer (score 1):

**In your case you are using standard des-based crypt algorithm**.

In this case salt is only returned as the first two characters of the output, so if you change only one letter in a very long salt string, it's very probable that you will get same string for multiple "almost the same" salts.

From PHP manual:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php

> The standard DES-based crypt() returns the salt as the first two
>   characters of the output. It also only uses the first eight characters
>   of str, so longer strings that start with the same eight characters
>   will generate the same result (when the same salt is used).

Comment: Umm... excuse me?  This statement goes against all sorts of cryptographic principles.  References please.

Comment: ok, I'm really confused.  So what are the two chars of the salt then ?  Is it '2a' 'us'.  So where is the salt in the string and where does the hashed password start ?

Comment: @Crontab he is using standard crypt in his example, isn't he?

Comment: @downvoter - any reasons for downvoting except for not understanding user questio?

Comment: @Crontab please check his question. He asked why he get the same result for multiple salts. And I was refering to his code in my answer. [edit] updated my answer to make it more obvious.

Comment: Indeed, Crontab, as far as I know I'm using Blowfish with 8 iterations.  So far, I understand, but the manual is not very clear about the several parts in the output string.  And thus the question remains why most outputs are the same.

Comment: @Crontab could please explain me the difference between "salt is only returned as the first two characters of the output" and "returns the salt as the first two characters of the output"? Maybe I am missing something.

I haven't said it uses 2 two characters from the salt, but salt is returned as two characters.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, its just ignoring the last character for some reason.  What a silly implementation.  Probably nothing to worry about.  There is no reasonably way you can increase the security past the limit imposed by the salt length restriction.

Comment: @user1529858 try this.  post results

Comment: actually it returns a yes, so Blowfish is used then, I guess.  You were right about dollar sign, but still same result.

Comment: Maybe it's treating the null terminator as part of the string (that would be a bug).  Try changing the 21st character.

Comment: well, changing 21th position gives weird result <br/>:                        $hash4 = crypt('test','$2a$08$useasillystringforsald$');<br/>
   echo 'hash4: '.$hash4.'<br/>';<br/>      hash4: $2a$08$useasillystringforsalOnUtWGdo1WqxrpPXy7Lrt0SHVxn5XeU6<br/>
hash5: $2a$08$useasillystringforsaley3TiRUWCAPaejcvjzQFYCRitqtaPur6<br/>
hash6: $2a$08$useasillystringforsaley3TiRUWCAPaejcvjzQFYCRitqtaPur6
   
   $hash5 = crypt('test','$2a$08$useasillystringforsale$');<br/>
   echo 'hash5: '.$hash5.'<br/>';            
   $hash6 = crypt('test','$2a$08$useasillystringforsalf$');<br/>

Comment: As a zero indexed string, I meant the 20th character.

Comment: that results in 3 different result strings indeed

Comment: I guess it's just not considering the last character as it's expected to.  A 21 digit salt should be sufficient.

Comment: so, should we consider this as a bug or a mistake in the php manual, which gives us following example : if (CRYPT_BLOWFISH == 1) {
    echo 'Blowfish:     ' . crypt('rasmuslerdorf', '$2a$07$usesomesillystringforsalt$') . "\n";

Comment: It's bugesque.  I revised my answer.  You might consider reporting steps to reproduce this, as well as the version of php you're using, and the operating system you're on.

Answer (score 0):

Need ending $:

```
$hash4 = crypt('test','$2a$08$useasillystringforsalfaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa$');
```